# Как в админке Django, на странице User (стандартного) добавить ссылку на другой раздел

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Есть такая модель

```
class Activities(models.Model):
    activities_user = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activities_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    activities_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    activities_start = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    activities_end = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    activities_duration = models.DurationField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.activities_name
```

Нужно, что бы, когда в админке, находясь на странице любого пользователя, там отображалось в виде ссылок все объекты Activities созданные данным пользователем. Очень много гуглил, не знаю даже в каком направлении двигаться, заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать [инлайнами](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin)

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from appname.models import Activities

admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserActivitiesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Activities


@admin.register(User)
class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserActivitiesInline ]
```

Если нужно, чтобы Activities отображались именно ссылками, то можно немного доработать UserActivitiesInline

```
class UserActivitiesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Activities
    fields = ('activity_link',)
    readonly_fields = fields

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def activity_link(self, obj):
        return u'<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(reverse('admin:appname_activities_change', args=(obj.pk,)), obj.activities_name)
    activity_link.allow_tags = True
    activity_link.short_description = Activities._meta.get_field('activities_name').verbose_name.title()
    activity_link.admin_order_field = 'activities_name'
```

[А ещё можно переопределить шаблон admin/change_form.html](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template).

P.S. Пара советов по стилю: во-перевых, лучше использовать название модели в единственном числе - Activity, во-вторых, у вас названия полей избыточны, зачем-то включают название модели.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ и за замечания по коду, буду делать, исправлять

Comment: Пробуйте. Если поможет, отметьте ответ решением, чтобы его могли легко найти другие пользователи.

Comment: Выдаёт вот такую ошибку
<class 'time_tracker.admin.UserActivitiesInline'>: (admin.E202) 'time_tracker.Activities' has no ForeignKey to 'auth.User'.
Я так понимаю, лучше создать дополнительное поле в модели с ForeignKey(auth.User)?

Comment: И правда, не обратил внимание, что поле activities_user имеет тип CharField. Да, нужно чтобы между моделями была связь.

Comment: Я просто уже делал связь через activities_user, но из-за этого умерла вся БД, сейчас попробую добавить новое поле

Comment: Ещё, можно вопрос, reverse из 
from audioop import reverse
или из
from audioop import reverse
 И ещё, код который вы написали на python2.7?

Comment: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse `appname` вам надо будет исправить на фактическое название приложения, в котором находится модель.

Comment: Код совместим со всеми версиями Python от 2.7 и выше.

Comment: На счёт appname сам догадался, но вот, что выдаёт Django, при заходе на страницу пользователя
Reverse for 'time_tracker_activities_change' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/time_tracker/activities/(.+)/$']
и
Reverse for 'time_tracker_activities_change' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/time_tracker/activities/(.+)/$']

Comment: Точно, забыл параметр! Исправил ответ.

Comment: Ошибка и вправду исчезла, но тут появилась такая 
_reverse_with_prefix() argument after * must be a sequence, not int

Comment: Вы, наверное, запятую пропустили после `obj.pk`. В args должен быть передан кортеж `args=(obj.pk,)`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за потраченное на меня время.